# how to get the first row among many satisfying a particular condition?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Suppose I have a table like below :

```
          COL_1                         COUNT_COL_1
          --------------------      ---------------
          rec_1                                 1
          rec_2                                 2
          rec_3                                 5
          rec_4                                 3
          rec_5                                 2
          rec_6                                 5
```

Now my requirement is to check for the maximum value in COUNT_COL_1 and fetch the corresponding value in COL_1. If in case multiple values in COL_1 is satisfying this condition (as in this case 'rec_3' and 'rec_6' both have maximum count of 5), then I have to select the first value in COL_1 (so in this case, I should fetch 'rec_3' as it is first among 'rec_3' and 'rec_5'). How can I achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `count_col_1` actually a column in your table, or is what you've shown the result of a query that does a `count`?

Comment: it is the result of a query that does a count.

Comment: OK, then I think my answer works; mhasan's answer is the same idea but assumed it was a fixed column...

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT * FROM 
    ( SELECT COL_1 
      FROM test
      ORDER BY COUNT_COL_1 desc,COL_1 asc
    )z
 WHERE ROWNUM=1
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/712f9f/9)

Answer (score 0):

You need an inner query ordered by the both the count (descending) and then the tie-breaking value; and then an outer query that just selects the first value:

```
select col_1 from (
  select col_1, count(*)
  from t42
  group by col_1
  order by count(*) desc, col_1
)
where rownum = 1;

COL_1    
----------
rec_3
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7ae09/1).